# Should I read/write a XML file to save data in a local Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, file-io, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple chrome extension. I need to create the ability to add sites URLs to a list, or read from the list.

I use the list to open the sites in the new tabs.

I'm looking for a way to have a data file I can write to, and read from. I was thinking on XML. I read there is a problem changing the content of files with Javascript.

Is XML the right choice for this kinda thing?

I should add that there is no web server, and the app will run locally, so maybe the problem websites are having are not same as this.

Before I wrote this question, I tried one thing, and started to feel insecure because it didn't work.

- I made a XML file called Site.xml:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

    <Sites>
  <site>
    <url>
      http://www.sulamacademy.com/AddMsgForum.asp?FType=273171&SBLang=0&WSUAccess=0&LocSBID=20375
    </url>
  </site>

  <site>
    <url>
      http://www.wow.co.il
    </url>
  </site>

  <site>
    <url>
      http://www.Google.co.il
    </url>
  </site>
```

- I made this script to read the data from him, and put in on the html file.

---

```
 function LoadXML() {
            var ajaxObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajaxObj.open('GET', 'Sites.xml', false);
            ajaxObj.send();

        var myXML = ajaxObj.responseXML;
        document.write('<table border="2">');
        var prs = myXML.getElementsByTagName("site");
        for (i = 0; i < prs.length; i++) {
            document.write("<tr><td>");
            document.write(prs[i].getElementsByName("url")[0].childNode[0].nodeValue);
            document.write("</td></tr>");
        }
        document.write("</table");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Chrome extensions cannot write to files on the real file system (a [virtual HTML5 filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5-filesystem/info) might be too complex for you).
2. For local apps, the best way of maintaining persistent settings is by using [`chrome.storage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) <sup>Chrome 20+</sup> or [`localStorage`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/local-storage/info).
3. When using `localStorage`, the data needs to be serialized. [JSON](http://json.org/) suits better than XML .
4. Never use `document.write` after the page has loaded, because he previous contents of the document will be wiped.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest a work around for this problem using "chrome.storage.local". First refer to [Google Guide](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) Then concerning your code. Do only two things:

1) Store them in sequence like this

```
key: site1 - value: www.example1.com
key: site2 - value: www.example2.com
key: site3 - value: www.example3.com
```

2) When retreiving, you should iterate starting from "site1" until there are no more :)